# Sharepoint 2007 - Navigation Folders

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, navigation

I am constructing a SharePoint website and we have a navigation menu bar showing links to pages within a site.  We have a site “abc” and within that there are pages, we are putting some within a navigation folder to give the illusion that they are a new site except its not.  Is there anyway to tell that you are in a folder, you can used the “has child nodes”, which does the job but I need to only go down where there is a folder and not a whole other site.

Thanks

Comment: Upload some code to show you're iterating through the objects.. you'd get a more accurate answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

- Every `SPWeb` object has a `SPFolderCollection` property named `Folders`
- Every `SPFolder` object has as `SPFolderCollection` property name `SubFolders`

With that, you can find all folders under a SharePoint site.

Comment: Thanks,

When I use this method the folder comes back as "" so I cant use this method.

Is there anyway to tell if you are on a subsite or a page??  Is there a property that I could use?